# Why do Java Anonymous Classes retain generic information at runtime?

Tags: java, generics, anonymous, erasure

While I was looking for a way to retain information about generic types at runtime in the context of JSON (de)serialization with Jackson, I found out that it's indeed possible to do so using [`TypeReference<T>`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.10/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference.html).
I then wanted to understand how and why it works, so I followed the link in the documentation, [which leads here](http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html).

I understand that there are some circumstances, such as with anonymous inner classes, where it is possible to know the generic type of a class even at runtime (I think it can be said the type erasure does not fully apply here), but I don't understand *why* : why bother adding this (fairly obscure) feature if it is only appliable to this particular case? Don't get me wrong, it is fairly handy to have it, but why does it exist in the first place?

Comment: Every *concrete* subclass retains information about the concretization of the type parameter, not only anonymous ones. its a pretty basic feature of type variables and obviously needed. I'm not sure what your actual question is?

Comment: Indeed, `A extends ArrayList<String>` and `B extends ArrayList<Integer>` are completely different beasts, even though both of their *superclasses* erase to `ArrayList`.